# Choose you own adventure: store player string in array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, variables, store

Trying to make the string "Abbot" the [1] slot of my basePlayer array. Basically they select the player in the switch and then the player string will be stored in array.

line 118

Help would be SUPER appreciated, program will run if you copy, paste, compile, and run.
Thank you for taking a look!!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

int main(){
Beep(251.63,100);
Beep(329.63,100);
Beep(392,100);
Beep(251.63,100);
Beep(329.63,100);
Beep(392,100);
Beep(251.63,100);
Beep(329.63,100);
Beep(392,100);

string playerList[6] = {"Abbot", "Seer", "Hellion", "Vagabond", "Knave","##QUIT##"};
string cityList[4] = {"city1","city2","city3","city4"};
string spiritList[4] = {"spirit1","spirit2","spirit3","spirit4",};
string yesNo[2] = {"yes","no"};
string name;
string player;
string city;
string spirit;
string basePlayer[4] = {name, player, city, spirit};



int pointer = 0;

SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "your name is " << name << "?" << endl;
basePlayer[0] = name;

while(true){

    system("cls");

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
    cout << basePlayer[0]<<" please choose your Adventurer:\n*tab* for description\n\n";


    for (int row = 0; row < 6; ++row){
        if(row == pointer){
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
            cout << playerList[row] << endl;}

        else{
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
            cout << playerList[row] << endl;}}

 while(true){

 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0){
        Beep(800,50);
    pointer -= 1;
    if (pointer == -1){
        pointer = 0;}
            break;}

 else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0){
        Beep(800,50);
    pointer += 1;
    if (pointer == 6){
        pointer = 0;}
            break;}

 else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_TAB) != 0){
        Beep(1200,50);
        Beep(1000,50);

    switch(pointer){
    case 0:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "AbbotFacts.\n\n*RightArrow* to become the Abbot\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 1:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "SeerFacts.\n\n*RightArrow* to become the Sear\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 2:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "HellionFacts.\n\n*RightArrow* to become the Hellion\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 3:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "VagabondFacts.\n\n*RightArrow* to become the Vagabond\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 4:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "KnaveFacts.\n\n*RightArrow* to become the Knave\n*ArrowDown* to return to TitleScreen";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 5:{return 0;}
        break;
        break;}}

 else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) != 0){
        Beep(1000,50);
        Beep(1200,50);


    switch(pointer){
    case 0:{
        system("cls");
        player = "Abbot";
        cout << basePlayer[0] << ", You have chosen the "<< basePlayer[1] << endl;


        Sleep(1000);
    }

        break;
    case 1:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Seer"<< endl;
        player="Seer";
        cout << basePlayer[1] << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 2:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Hellion"<< endl;
        player="Hellion";
        cout << basePlayer[1] << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 3:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Vagabond" << endl;
        player="Vagabond";
        cout << basePlayer[1] << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 4:{
        system("cls");
        cout << "You have chosen the Knave"<< endl;
        player="Knave";
        cout << basePlayer[1] << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
        break;
    case 5:{return 0;
    break;}
    break;}}
 }
 Sleep(150);
 }
 }
```

Comment: What is the variable 'player' being used for ?

Comment: I can just put the whole game script in there.

Comment: I think there are way too many unknowns for this to be an answerable question, I suggest you read up on the guidelines for asking a good question, you're more like asking 'how do I do a game' rather than 'how do I store a string in an array', I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There we go, thanks for taking a look guys! If you run the program, it should be easier to know what I'm trying to do. Sorry if I didn't explain well. Basically trying to make a final basePlayer array with 4 rows of info. {name, player, city, spirit}

Comment: Sorry my question might be bad

Comment: I just want to change make the variable player to = "Abbot" and then get stored in the array basePlayer in the [1] spot... if that makes sense.... I'm very new. Just started 2 weeks ago. Maybe if you run the program it will help

Comment: To select a player to press the Right Arrow, by the way

Comment: Just changed *enter* to *RightArrow* in the directions displayed on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is assign player to basePlayer[1] after setting the player value.

```
switch(pointer){
case 0:{
    player = "Abbot";
    basePlayer[1] = player;
    cout << "You have chosen the "<< basePlayer[1] << endl;
```

Comment: Woooooo!! Thank you chmike!! that fixed my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you have a read up on how character arrays work in C++, and memory allocation.

If you want a simpler solution, you might like the std string library, which handles most of the memory and copying side for you.

I seriously think you might want to try something simpler first, or at least look in to an oop design, which might be simpler in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help! yeah, I'm a newbie, I should probably do something simpler. I've just gotten myself wrapped up in finishing this thing lol

Answer (score 0):

It would be much, much better to store this data in a structure rather than an array. This would allow you to group other player data that may not be represented as a string.

```
struct PlayerData
{
  std::string m_Name;
  std::string m_Player;
  std::string m_City;
  std::string m_Spirit;
  int m_MaxHealth;
};
...
PlayerData basePlayer;

basePlayer.m_Name = playerList[playerSelection];
```

Better yet why not have a class store this data, allowing you to control access to it and also perform operations with the data.

```
class Player
{
public:
  Player( const std::string& name, const std::string& player, const std::string& city, const std::string& spirit );
  virtual ~Player();

  std::string GetName() const;
  void ReduceHealth( int damage );

private:

  std::string m_Name;
  std::string m_Player;
  std::string m_City;
  std::string m_Spirit;
  int m_MaxHealth;

};
```

You may want to read up more on C++ itself and it's features before attempting a to write a whole game.

Comment: Ok, I will look into structures right now. I haven't learned about them yet. Thank you for bringing that to my attention!

Comment: You may want to look into structures and much more about c++ before you create a whole game. I remember when I started game development, learn your tools before you rush in and create something with them.